# Django DetailView - display boolean from models as checkboxes

Tags: django, checkbox, detailview

There's a number of snippets to display booleans in Django Forms as checkboxes (i.e. specifying Checkbox as a widget). For instance (assuming a boolean field defined in the model for bar):

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['bar'] 
        widgets = {
            'bar' : CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'required checkbox form-control'}),   
        }
```

However I also need to display a (disabled) checkbox in DetailView (client says so). But I can't figure out an elegant way to do this, since I don't have a form meta for details view...

My current thinking is something like this (bootstrap checkbox):

```
<div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" {% if foo.bar %}checked{% endif %} disabled>Bar
   </label>
<\div>
```

Any way to accomplish this in a fashion closer to the Form's  widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the view get you form and set initial value
get the model object and set bars initial value

```
form = YourForm(initial={'bar':modelObject.bar })
```

and then send the form to the template and simply render
like form.bar
you can disable this with many ways

like

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['bar'] 
        widgets = {
            'bar' : CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'required checkbox form-control','disabled':'disabled or true'}),   
        }
```

or find and use any template filter to add attribute to form field

Comment: So if I get you correctly - even if I'm using say Class FooDetail(DetailView), I can still instantiate my FooForm (in which I have set the checkbox as I want), and set its value to whatever bar value is in the model. Then I pass it on to my template (with get_context_data for example). Then in my template I simply {{ form.bar }} instead of what I posted above.

I guess I'll have to make a 2nd form (since for the actual form, I do want bar enabled) but would work indeed.